# TFS Powertools 2010 Shell Integration with Windows Explorer - Attempts to connect to server fails

Tags: tfs-power-tools

We have Team Foundation Server 2010 installed on a domain server with Visual Studio 2010 installed on the client side connected to the domain. All works well.

We then installed TFS Powertools 2010 so that we could use the TFS facilities integrated with Windows Explorer. This doesn't seem to work - the Team Foundation Server sub menu which is present in the context menu has only one entry - "Reconnect to server". When this is selected an error is returned saying "Unable to connect to Team Foundation Server".

I would have expected a dialogue box requesting credentials to be input but this does not happen. Does anyone know where these credentials are stored or some other work around? I've seen similar questions but no definitive answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can store the credentials in the Windows Credentials Manager (Windows 7). You can find that in the control panel.

Comment: Add the bare server name only, as a "Windows Credential". No http://, no port, no path.

Comment: Good to know question is resolved but I wan't to share my scenario where TFS credentials are different from Windows Credentials(not on Active Directory). What to do for default windows shell extension?